# transaction aborted error message notification change

Tags: jsf, message

I have added unique constraints to my database table to prevent duplicate entries. I have tested it and its working fine, On my page when when I try to submit the same values I get a message saying transaction aborted which means its working fine, is there a way to change the message:

> Transaction aborted

To something like:

> Task already assigned to user!

If so how would I change it?
If Possible to only change the message for unique constraint violation that would be great.

I choose the values and save them with create method:

```
public String create() {
        try {
            getFacade().create(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("webConstants/Bundle").getString("TimeLoggingDetailCreated"));
            recreateModel();
            return prepareCreate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("webConstants/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And display the message on the page like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block" >
                <h:messages infoClass="alert alert-success" errorClass="alert alert-danger" layout="row col-12" warnClass="alert alert-info" fatalClass="alert"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

Stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-1-1-1' for key 'logging_unique'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO MY_LOGGING (CUSTOMERS_ID, EMPLOYEES_EMPLOYEE_NO, PROJECTS_ID, TASKS_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(za.co.company.entity.Logging[ id=null ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2187.create(Unknown Source)
    at za.co.company.session.__EJB31_Generated__LoggingFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at za.co.company.controller.LoggingController.create(LoggingController.java:89)
    at za.co.company.controller.LoggingController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-1-1-1' for key 'logging_unique'
Error Code: 1062
```

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: Answer depends on where exactly the current message is coming from and how exactly you're currently displaying that message. This information is nowhere available in the question and hence this question is unanswerable.

Comment: hi, its a crud application that I'm trying new things on, I have added the code to the question

Comment: How exactly are you unable to change the error message? With this code, it's a bit too obvious in such way that I fail to imagine and understand how exactly you failed in this. A little bit of logical thinking and common sense should already have hinted that you'd just have to add a new message to the bundle and reference it instead of `"PersistenceErrorOccured"`, right?

Comment: @BalusC In the bundle: PersistenceErrorOccured=A persistence error occurred. so "PersistenceErrorOccured" is not called in the first place, so even if I create a new message in the bundle and reference it it will not be used? my question stated that I get a message saying transaction aborted, not Persistence error occurred. the error code is 1062 and comes from org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException. so my question: how do I change the "Transaction aborted" error text?

Comment: Okay, that's then indeed a serious problem. Actually, a strange one either as you've there a generic catch-all on `Exception`. How exactly is the "Transaction aborted" error presented? In a JavaScript dialog which you would only see in Mojarra when `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is set to `Development`? Are you also getting a stack trace in the server log? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: @BalusC I added everything to question, thanks.

Comment: How exactly is the "Transaction aborted" error presented?

Answer (score 0):

> SHORT VERSION  :   Just remove the "e, " in your JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(...)

It seems you are using generated Code from Netbeans like me :-)
I ran into the same problem, but I found the problems source ..
in Class JSFUtil is a method addErrorMessage(...) which is called by your Exception which looks up for a localized String of your Exception (EJBException) and also found it.

The Problem - your second Parameter "String defaultMsg" is not used in this case

```
public static void addErrorMessage(Exception ex, String defaultMsg) {
    String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    System.out.println("DefaultMsg: " + defaultMsg);
    System.out.println("LocalMsg: " + msg);

    if (msg != null && msg.length() > 0) {
        addErrorMessage(msg);
    } else {
        addErrorMessage(defaultMsg);
    }
}
```

So you can rewrite that method or or just use addErrorMessage(String msg) in your try..catch-block which directly returns your own String from Bundle.properites file

```
public void create() {
        try {
            getFacade().create(current);
            recreateModel();
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("StandortCreated"));
        } catch (EJBException e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("YourOwnFromBundle"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }
```

Regards Chris